# Angular 4, URLSearchParams, standard QueryEncoder and equal sign with x-www-form-urlencoded POSTs

Tags: forms, angular, http, post, urlencode

using URLSearchParams in a POSt body generally works in Angular.

However, I've just noticed that is I try to post the equal character in a string, the QueryEncoder doesn't encode it and leaves it there as a '=' sign so the right part of the string is cut on the server.

I've checked the standard QueryEncoder and I've seen the = replacement is done on purpose, so I've created my own QueryEncoder to fix the issue.

However, I'm not sure this is a good approach and I've noticed that using URLSearchParams as form body is suggested in many places.

Is there a better and safer way to do it? I feel like Angular should provide at least a standard "FormQueryEncoder" for this use case or clearly discourage the usage.

**Edit: adding some code example:**

This is the simplified version of the problem:

```
let formParams = new URLSearchParams();
formParams.set('longDescription', 'This = That');

let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
  method: RequestMethod.Put,
  headers: headers,
  body: formParams,
  search: queryParameters
});

this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
```

On the server side, it was sending the '=' not encoded so I was only getting the string `This` as `longDescription` value.

To fix it, I've created a custom QueryEncoder:

```
export class FormQueryEncoder {
  encodeKey(k: string): string { return encodeURIComponent(k); }
  encodeValue(v: string): string { return encodeURIComponent(v); }
}
```

And I've used it with the URLSearchParams I'm using as body:

```
let formParams = new URLSearchParams('', new FormQueryEncoder());
```

Dem

Comment: please provide us a code snippet of how you are triyng to send this string

Comment: Hello, I've edited the question, let me know if it's more clear now, thanks!

Comment: ok, it's exactly what you already know: 

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058

Comment: thanks! I've missed that! I'll follow it and use the workaround in the meantime...cheers!